# "Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance" - Error When Adding Search Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, search, unrecognized-selector

I just added a search bar to my iPhone app which should search through a TableViewController of songs.  However, when I run my app on my iPhone, it freezes with a black screen and I get this error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance` on this line:

```
MPMediaItem *rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in this block:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        songs = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        songs = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    return cell;
}
```

This is my implementation code:

```
@implementation SongsViewController
{
    NSArray *searchResults;
    NSArray *songs;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MPMediaQuery *songsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    songs = [songsQuery items];  
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [songs count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        songs = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        songs = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    MPMediaItem *rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [rowItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [songs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

I do not understand what's wrong?  The error is: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPConcreteMediaItem objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178221e20'.`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you bother to Google that message?

Comment: Voting to reopen because there is nothing in the answers to that "duplicate" question that in any way would help solve the problem in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code:

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    songs = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    songs = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

MPMediaItem *rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to this:

```
MPMediaItem *rowItem;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    rowItem = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    rowItem = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get a SIGABRT error - '*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MPConcreteMediaItem 0x1782297a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.''

Comment: Which exact line of code causes that error?

Comment: It came up on line '        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));' in the file Supporting Files > main.m

Comment: Most likely this new error (unrelated to your original question) is coming from your search predicate. Close out this question since we solved the error asked about in this question. If needed, post a new question about the new error. But first, you need to setup Xcode for better debugging so you can do some of your own debugging first. See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Okay, I'll check out that link.  Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @downvoter please explain so we all can learn.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252531/581994

Comment: @HotLicks So you downvoted my good answer because you think the question was bad? That's sad. There was nothing bad about the question. I vote to close many bad questions. This wasn't one and I certainly don't deserve a downvote because someone doesn't like the question.

Comment: "Unrecognized selector" is in the top 2-3 Objective-C questions that are asked here.  If the OP has exerted *any effort at all* trying to find an answer on his own he wouldn't have needed to ask a question, or, at the very least, would have been able to ask a more targeted one.  There no way this was a "good question".

Comment: @HotLicks I don't wish to get in a big debate over this one but just because the question is about an "unrecognized selector" error doesn't mean it is automatically a duplicate of some generic other question on the same error. This question showed code, it showed the full error. That's better than 80% of the actual bad questions. Even if the OP read some other related questions it doesn't mean the OP would understand how to fix their code to solve the error. This was not a blatantly bad question. Don't punish people trying to help. Something to consider.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree with that meta statement in principal, but I disagree that this is an example of such a case.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the link to debugging from RayW, I've been reading it over the past day and it's helped me a lot!  I decided to add a UITableView on a UIViewController rather than use a UITableViewController, so hopefully adding  a search bar will be easier this way.  Thanks for your help again, I appreciate it a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is happening because of the following line:

```
songs = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You are assigning `MPMediaItem` to the `NSArray` object. And next time when you try to use `[songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` It'll crash.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, how would I fix this?  What do I replace 'songs = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];' with?  Thanks

Comment: @user3127576: remove that else part and check

Comment: Thanks, it now loads and shows the songs but when I tap a character on the keyboard in the search bar, I get a SIGABRT error - "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MPConcreteMediaItem 0x17003a780> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'" :S Thanks

Comment: @user3127576: these crashes come from your search display controllers delegate. Check that NSPredicate

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, everything seems fine there?  :S